# Should I post an issue for variation in parameters

Tags: flutter, github, dart, github-issues

The parameter for **StatefulBuilder's** builder function are different in the website **flutter.dev** and the documentation pop-up window in **android studio** or **vs code**.  In official website documentation it says that the second parameter is a **StateSetter** whereas in **IDE** it says **void Function(void Function ())**.

So, should I post it as an issue in the flutter's github for updation of documentation ? or shall I let it be ? I mean is there something I don't know technically ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`StateSetter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StateSetter.html) is a typedef for function signature `void Function(VoidCallback fn)`, and [`VoidCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html) is a typedef for `void Function()`, so basically

```
StateSetter = void Function(void Function())
```

It is just that IDEs usually resolve the typedefs to most primitive values, which is usually handy, but sometimes confusing as well.